# Use \nameref to refer to annex

Tags: undefined, nameref

I use my Universty's template Latex (University of Montreal) for my these and I'm facing an error I don't know how to fix it:
I used template's commands to create annexes (\Annexe) but it's not a perfect way to me cause when I want to refer them in my text with "\nameref", I get "REFERENCES" instead the name of my annex.
I had found a way to fix it by doing this:

```
\section*{\Annexe{Entrevue avec Frédéric Auger}}\label{section:Fred}
```

I know that's really not clean to put a command in another, but that fix all of my problems cause now:

- \nameref refer to the name of my annex (thanks to \section*, otherwise i get "REFERENCES" instead);
- in my list of annexes I get the name of my annex (thanks to \Annexe);
- at the bottom of each annex, its headname is in the good style, i.e. the style of annex's head and not the style of a section (thanks to \Annexe again).

However, now my Messages/Log detect an error for each "\nameref{}" that I use cause it find "\Annex" argument before the real name... But it's working ! My PDF is exactly how I want.

Here is the error that I have :

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \Annexe
```

So my question is : how can I fix it without losing any solution, or how can I ignore there messages? I don't want to use "latex -interaction nonstopmode" cause I always want to know if I make other errors...
I tried to find another solution in modifing my .sty file, but I don't understand how it work...

Here is how \Annexe is created in my master document :

```
\ifthenelse{\equal{\AnnexesPresentes}{O}}{
    \appendix%
    \newcommand{\Annexe}[1]{\annexe{#1}\setcounter{figure}{0}\setcounter{table}{0}\setcounter{footnote}{0}}%
```

And here what I found in my .sty file about \Annexe :

```
    \def\@makeappendixhead#1{%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \centering
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \if@english
            \normalsize\bfseries APPENDIX\space\thechapter
        \else       
            \normalsize\bfseries ANNEXE\space\thechapter
        \fi
        %\par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@
        \space\space\space\space
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
     \normalsize \bfseries {\MakeUppercase{#1}}\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
```

And :

```
    \newcommand\annexe{\if@openright\cleardoublepage\else\clearpage\fi
                    \thispagestyle{plain}%
                    \global\@topnum\z@
                    \@afterindentfalse
                    \secdef\@annexe\@schapter}

\def\@annexe[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                       \if@mainmatter
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \if@english
                           \addcontentsline{app}{annexe}%
                               {\protect\numberline{Appendix\nobreakspace\thechapter}#1}%
                         \else
                             \addcontentsline{app}{annexe}%
                               {\protect\numberline{Annexe\nobreakspace\thechapter}#1}%
                         \fi  
                       \else
                         \addcontentsline{app}{annexe}{#1}%
                       \fi
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{app}{annexe}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makeappendixhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makeappendixhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}
```

And :

```
\newcommand\listofappendices{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
     \if@english
       \chapter*{LIST OF APPENDICES}%
         \addcontentsline{toc}{compteur}{LIST OF APPENDICES}%
     \else
       \chapter*{LISTE DES ANNEXES}%
         \addcontentsline{toc}{compteur}{LISTE DES ANNEXES}%
     \fi  


    \@starttoc{app}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

I hope my problem is clearly explain...
Thanks !

Comment: `\Annexe` is not a standard command and you have given no hint of its definition. I don't think your question can be answered unless you give more information.

Comment: Which kind of informations can I give you ?

Comment: preferably a small complete document including a defintion of `\Annexe` copied from your thesis class that shows the problem. Currently your question is essentially, "I have used `\AbbHjhjgrkkka` and it generates errors, how can they be avoided". What answer can anyone give?